# the usage of "having come into"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, usage

I can understand the basic meaning of this sentence, but I'm confused with the usage of "having come into" and "-ened" of "blackened"

"If they’ve been used for a while, they become blackened or discolored in some other way as a result of having come into contact with high heat. "

thanks :)

Comment: *blackened* is the past tense of [*blacken*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/blacken). *having come into* just means it went from not touching the heat to touching (making contact with) the heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Come into contact" is a multi-word compound verb meaning "touch" or "be exposed to." The word "having" is added to create the [perfect tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar)), similar to this sentence: "She didn't order any food, having eaten before arriving."

If you simplify the sentence by rewriting it without the perfect tense, you'd get this: "...as a result of coming into contact with high heat."

As the earlier commenter pointed out, "blacken" simply means "to become black in color."